# Iterating and Populating text in a text file

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to solve a problem using the OSX terminal.

I need to create a text file that takes a series of inputs and concatenates and iterates from those inputs a series of filenames in text form within a single text file.

For example, inputs:

```
Name Starting (musical) Note - (scale goes c1, c#1, d1, d#1, e1, f1, f#1, g1, g#1, a1, a#1, b1, b#1, c2, c#2….)
Ending Note
Variable 1
Variable 2
```

Output being the contents of a plain text file like the following:

```
Name-C1-var1-var2
Name-C#1-var1-var2
Name-D1-var1-var2
etc.
```

I'm not a programmer so any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` to edit the data to the form required.

The `-r` option enables extended regular expressions.
The `-e` option allows multiple commands to be 'chained'. The first substitution adds the hyphens, the second substitution removes the final hyphen at the end of the line. `touch` creates the filename generated by the sub-shell containing the sed commands.

```
while read line 
do  
   touch $(echo "$line" | sed -r -e 's/[a-g]+[#]*[1-8]+/&-/g' -e 's/-$//'); 
done < data.txt
```